# Confusing verb "make" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

> God **made** me to help others.

I am very confused as to **whether God himself wants to help others by making me** or **God want me to help others.**

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that it isn't the same as *God made me help others* (= *God forced me to help others*) - that idiom requires a bare infinitive clause, not a to-infinitive clause. [I don't think you thought it was this, but others might be confused]

So, *made* here is literal: *created*, or *formed*.

The to-infinitive used in this way (where the main predicate does not have a special requirement for it) is to convey purpose. So it means:

> God made me in order that I can help others

However, in my reading, the purpose here is ambiguous - perhaps deliberately so. 
It could mean

> God made me as a tool to help others with;

or

> God made me in such a way that I would be moved to help others, or it would be my purpose to help others.